# Query MongoDB on array of objects with multiples filters

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

In a `Users` collection, we have an array fields `events` which stores different categories of events. This is an array of objects with 2 fields : `event`, `category`.

We try to set a query in MongoDB to get a list of users according two conditions :

- First, we want to filter in `events` the events with at least 1 event with a "Analytics" category
- Then, we want to filter in the filtered array, the `events` whose the last event with a "Analytics" category is "Views".

Here an exemple :

```
[
    {
      _id: "123",
      events: [
        {
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Views"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: "456",
      events: [
        {
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        },
        {
          category: "Payment",
          event: "failed"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: "127",
      events: [
        {
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Views"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The result should be :

```
[{
    "_id": "127",
    "events": [
      {
        "category": "Payment",
        "event": "ok"
      },
      {
        "category": "Analytics",
        "event": "Clicks"
      },
      {
        "category": "Analytics",
        "event": "Views"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

We try with the query based on aggregating and grouping but it is not working :

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "users.events.category": "Analyics",
      "users.events.event": "Views"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      user: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$user" }
  }
])
```

Do you know how to solve our issue ?

**UPDATE**

Here the new set of data on which we need the query:

```
[{
    user_infos: [{
      _id: "123",
      events: [{
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Views"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    user_infos: [{
      _id: "456",
      events: [{
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        },
        {
          category: "Payment",
          event: "failed"
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    user_infos: [{
      _id: "127",
      events: [{
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Views"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: In your example, 1. both `_id`s are "123" which is confusing; 2. In The requested result the last event is not `"Views"`, is this on purpose ? Is the `date` missing?

Comment: I have edited my question (and you can ignore the `date` field).
Indeed, the main purpose is to get the users whose the last event of Analytics category is Views

Comment: But in your example response the last event is not "Views"...

Comment: The last event of `Analytics` is `Clicks` in all documents. Based on the conditions you provided, the result is empty, i. e. none is matching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all users which their last event of `category: "Analytics"` is with `event: "Views"`, one option is:

```
db.users.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "events.category": "Analytics",
      "events.event": "Views"
    },
    {$expr: {$eq: [
          {$getField: {
              input: {$last: {$filter: {
                    input: "$events",
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$this.category", "Analytics"]}
              }}},
              field: "event"
          }},
          "Views"
    ]}}
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rPTvPqwu_Jb)

Comment: how to modify the query in the case where each objects in a array ? 
For instance : 
[
    {userInfos: [{
      _id: "123",
      events: [
        {
          category: "Payment",
          event: "ok"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Views"
        },
        {
          category: "Analytics",
          event: "Clicks"
        }
      ]
    }
]
 }
]

Comment: I don't understand the question, are there few users inside a `user` document in "users" collection? If this is the case this is an entirely different question with a different expected result and a different strategy. If this is the case please ask a new question

Comment: I have edited the question with the new set of data. We have an array on the top level of the document. Tell me if the new set is clear or if I should create a new question

Comment: You should create a new question, this is the best practice. Regardless, if this new structure is a result of an aggregation pipeline, it should be better to intervene before the grouping of users.